# Is 'improvs' a normal abbreviation of 'improvisation'?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

The 'improvisation' was apparently abbreviated as 'improvs' in [this scenario](https://www.gsb.stanford.edu/insights/power-no-how-boundaries-help-us-live-more-empowered-lives):

> For example, when we are brainstorming or when we are conducting some sort of idea generation at work, or even when we are talking to our kids, in those situations, we want to use the **improvs** rule, the “yes, and” rule.

However, the usual abbreviation seems to be "improv". (See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improv), for example.) Is this abbreviation normally acceptable in other contexts?

Comment: No "s". At least in my English. But then perhaps those who say "maths" might abbreviate other fields this way by analogy... I doubt it, though.

Comment: Can't listen to the audio, but it could easily be "improv's" (possessive, referring to the rule which belongs to "the improv")

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is obvious by looking at the previous paragraph in the transcript: "As you and our listeners know, perhaps the most important and famous rule in improvisation is to say 'yes, and.'" It's quite clear that this "improvisation rule" is what is meant when this speaker says "improvs rule".

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I am asking about the usage of the 'improvs' in other contexts.

Comment: @LernerZhang Yes, it's good that you've edited the question to add that part, which I think is good. However, the title still asks the original question. Please edit it some more, or I'd be willing to do that if you don't mind.

Comment: Actually, I went ahead and edited it (and retracted my CV). Please feel free to change or revert if I misrepresented what you were trying to ask.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I just saw your message. Thanks!